# sudoers is world writable

Tags: permissions, rhel, sudo

I wanted to modify the `sudoers` file, and by mistake, to be able to open it, changed the permissions from 440 to 777. Now when wanting to open it, it no longer allows me, and the error that comes out is:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin.
```

It is worth mentioning that I am not an administrator; only my user belongs to the root group, but now I can no longer run anything like `sudo`.

Attached errors and tests that you performed.
[image]

Comment: Salvador I think your screenshot is an attempt at responding to [the answer from Bib](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671990/100397). If so, (a) please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397), and (b) please re-read what @Bib suggested - what you entered and what they suggested _do not match_.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the root password, then run `su - root -c "chmod 440 /etc/sudoers"`

If not, then you'll have to boot from some media, mount the root partition, then run the `chmod` command from there.

Comment: `setgit: Operation not permitted` is the result.
Can you explain the other scenario with the correct commando's please? @Bib